# How to Combine IF and INDEX MATCH with two conditioncs?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, vlookup

Can someone help me with  my project? So this is what Ive got to do. Id like to build up an if-index-match formula for the I:I cells, here's the logic.

This is the formula im working on and its not working:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D8,$E$2:$E$1315,1,FALSE)), INDEX($M$2:M7,MATCH(2,1/($D$2:D7=D8))), VLOOKUP(B8,$AC$2:$AD$101,2,0))
```

IF itemcode already exists in item movement sheet, get the last matching value(ending qty) of the itemcode entered in item movement sheet, if not, fetch the value of the item code in another sheet STOCK CODE for the beiginning quantity.

Is it possible for me to creata a formula combining if-index match and vlook up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? What part of the formula are you stuck with exactly?

Comment: This is the formula im working on and its not working :( =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D8,$E$2:$E$1315,1,FALSE)), INDEX($M$2:M7,MATCH(2,1/($D$2:D7=D8))), VLOOKUP(B8,$AC$2:$AD$101,2,0))

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding the problem as you have one condition in the narrative scenario... if exists, then do this, else do that.  Can you elaborate?  Additionally, if this is an array formula, have you ensure to use ctrl+shift+enter?